# Copy multiple BigQuery tables using BigQuery Jobs API

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed in BigQuery Jobs API for the Copy task:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource

there exists a input for "sourceTables":

```
"copy": {
  "sourceTables": [
    {
      "projectId": string,
      "datasetId": string,
      "tableId": string
    }
  ],
```

However we can only define a singular "destinationTable" rather than "destinationTables":

```
  "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": string,
    "datasetId": string,
    "tableId": string
  },
```

Is there a way I can use the above API to copy multiple source tables from one Dataset into another Dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create multiple destination tables you'll need to run multiple jobs. If you want to do these all at once, you can use a batch request (docs for the HTTP API [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch). Python docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch), and Java [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Batch).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using batch request via Java API: