# Efficient way to copy date-sharded table in BigQuery via the command-line bq utility?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to copy a date-sharded table to another dataset via the `bq` utility?

My current solution is generating a bash script to copy each day one-by-one and splitting the work, but more efficient would be to do everything in parallel:

```
#!/bin/sh
bq cp old_dataset.table_20140101 new_dataset_20140101
..
bq cp old_dataset.table_20171001 new_dataset_20171001
```

Comment: Can you share your bash script? I'm confused by _"copy each day one-by-one and splitting the work"_.

Comment: I've added the script, which I autogenerated from the command-line via vim. The list can be split across `n` scripts, where `n` is the amount of parallelism, but this is very tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple source tables but only a single destination table (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139022/copy-multiple-bigquery-tables-using-bigquery-jobs-api)), so this may not work for you. However, if your data is date-partitioned (instead of sharded) then you can copy the table in one command.

**I recommend you [convert the sharded table into a date-partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#converting_dated_tables_into_a_partitioned_table) which will be effectively copying all the sharded tables to a new table.** You can do this with the following command:

```
bq partition old_dataset.table_ new_dataset.partitioned
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep the old structure since this is a backup which corresponds to old scripts and software addressing it in the old-fashioned way. (I am migrating to daily-partitioned tables and thus doing this backup.)